# Is asking a “list-like” question regarding incompatible 32-bit apps in macOS Catalina off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

The subject pretty much says it all: Is asking a “list-like” question regarding incompatible 32-bit apps in macOS Catalina off-topic?

I am well aware list-like questions (aka: questions that inspire lists of stuff) is pretty much frowned upon on Stack Exchange sites. But considering the major shift away from 32-bit apps in macOS Catalina (10.15) in favor of a pure 64-bit OS, I think there is value in having something like this in the community.

I’m particularly thinking of folks who use legacy audio hardware with new systems from vendors that — for whatever reason — don’t have 32-bit applications or drivers. This is a fairly large macOS user community and having some comprehensive list/discussion thread would be of value and would be appreciated.

That said, I understand the downside of this kind of stuff as well: Out of control postings, “me too” posts and general noise.

So is there a way of posting a question like this here without breaking any norms?

Comment: This is the kind of thing covered by such as [RoaringApps](https://roaringapps.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up in Meta first!

IMHO such questions are a bad fit for Ask Different even as a community wiki

- Compatibility information people post in Ask Different may get outdated, with the poster not coming back to update it later on.
- The primary point of reference for compatibility issues or inquiries should be the website of the vendor.
- Vendors may have alternative products or workarounds available even if they discontinue a 32-bit application, which again is only accurate on their website.

So while I see the value of having this list, I doubt that there is a way to maintain this on Ask Different with the quality and accuracy people tend to expect from posts and answers here.

Comment: Agreed. I suppose we could have a generic question similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365596/168832) with a generic answer such as mine, but in the end it just refers people to an offsite resource.

Comment: Or [My Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216019/incompatible-software-for-next-osx) which was well received.